# Unable to use QT in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, qt

I have installed 'qt-vsaddin-msvc2017-2.3.0' for using QT in Visual Studio 2017, but there are some issues after installation. First thing is that I can not modify QT project Settings in Qt VS Tools since it is grey. After I restart VS, it keeps showing that 'Qt Visual Studio Tools Version 2.3.2: initializing...' and doesn't go on. Is there something I miss when I install qt-vsaddin?
[image]
[image]

Comment: and also shows 'The 'Vsix' package did not load correctly after VS restart

Comment: Have you configure the Qt-Add-in?

Comment: @Darem I think there is something wrong with my VS 2017. It works with VS 2015.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering this question a bit late because I ran into this problem myself today. The problem is your VS2017 is not up to date -- You need **at least** version 15.8; currently 15.9 is released. Odds are your `ActivityLog.xml` looks similar to Pavel Celba's answer here in which it's having trouble loading a specific version of the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading assembly`. In order to fix the issue, you're going to have to do one of two things:

1. Update your Visual Studio Community/Professional/Enterprise to the latest version.
2. Downgrade your version of the Qt vsaddin to 2.2.2. You can obtain the 2.2.2 release, [here](https://download.qt.io/archive/vsaddin/2.2.2/). If you need a previous version because your version is even earlier, go to the parent directory of that link.

Once you've installed 2.2.2 or have obtained the Visual Studio 15.9 update, it should be working correctly.

I also had this issue because my VS version is 15.4 but I can't connect to the internet on that computer.

Comment: my studio version was also 15.6. after upgrade it to latest it's fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing qt-vsaddin-msvc2017-2.3.2.vsix . If it fails you will probably need to reinstall VS 2017.

Comment: yes, I think there is something wrong with my VS 2017. It works with VS 2015. I have already uninstall my VS 2017. sad

Comment: If this was the solution, please mark it as "answered".

Answer (score 0):

We have same problem here - the error shown is:

```
<entry>
    <record>334</record>
    <time>2019/02/25 12:48:44.893</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [Vsix]Source: &apos;QtVsTools&apos; Description: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, Version=15.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.&#x000D;&#x000A;System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, Version=15.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.&#x000D;&#x000A;File name: &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, Version=15.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos;&#x000D;&#x000A;   at QtVsTools.Vsix.InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress`1 progress)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass16_0.&lt;&lt;Microsoft-VisualStudio-Shell-Interop-IAsyncLoadablePackageInitialize-Initialize&gt;b__1&gt;d.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.RethrowException(AggregateException e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean ignoreUIThreadCheck)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.GetResult()&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.&#x000D;&#x000A;To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.&#x000D;&#x000A;Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.&#x000D;&#x000A;To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].&#x000D;&#x000A;</description>
    <guid>{15021976-647E-4876-9040-2507AFDE45D2}</guid>
    <hr>80070002</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
</entry>
```

Our Visual Studio version is: 
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017
Version 15.5.1

We cannot update to newest update due to company policies.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with my VS 2017. It works with VS 2015

Comment: If you downgrade to 2.2.2 that I've noted in my answer, you should be able to resolve your issue. I'm currently running 15.4 because of company policies as well and this was my resolution to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect form internet and install Qt vsaddin 2.2.2 then run VS2017 go to Tools>Extensions and Updates> select "Qt Visual Studio Tools" > and then uncheck  "Automatically update this extension".