# How can i import Visual studio based project to Qt Creator?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qt-creator

I am using Visual Studio to debug and build my project in Windows environment. On Linux, I use Qt creator.

Now I want to use Qt Creator in Windows instead of Visual Studio.

How can I do this? Do I need to create a BAT file for this?

Comment: [Importing and Exporting Projects](https://doc.qt.io/qtvstools/qtvstools-importing-and-exporting-projects.html)

Comment: Thanks for giving some light. DO you know why "Create new basic.pro" is disable din my extention

Comment: [Unable to use Qt in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54879249/unable-to-use-qt-in-visual-studio-2017)